# Attachments in Play! Framework on dotcloud

Tags: java, playframework, dotcloud

I uploaded files to the server using BLOB db type on play framework. In the application.conf file I have

`attachments.path=home/dotcloud/uploads`

But I couldn't find the files on the server.

The issue is that if I restart my www service, then I lose all my files, I only have the db records.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are two issues in here. First your path lack a initial '/' to be a full path (I'm assuming that was your intention):

```
attachments.path=/home/dotcloud/uploads
```

Second, I'm not sure that your Play server will have rights to write to that folder, as it's outside the application context path. Default folder is local to the application and Play can write it, not so sure about other folders though. You should double check that.

Comment: Are you talking about UNIX access rights here, or about some extra filesystem security enforced by Play! or the JVM itself? (I'm familiar with the DotCloud platform, but not with the Play! framework...)

Comment: I was thinking on UNIX rights to write to that location, yes.